# OpenGL: When and how often am I supposed to call glLineWidth, glPointSize, glLineStyle?

Tags: opengl

As far as I know it is common practice to call `glColor4f` or the like each time before drawing an object or primitive.

But what about point and line style properties?

- Is it normal to call `glLineSize` and `glPointSize` very often?
- Should I store a backup of the current point size and set it back after drawing, or simply call `glPointSize` before drawing any point, even ones which use the default size?

Comment: i would prefer call it before you use it, so you have no chance of "leaking" different sizes, less graphical bugs. i dont know if its slower, but i guess you could always keep track of it. but definitely you should call it before you use lines. for example: if you draw million lines in a loop, call the function before the loop (if the size doesnt change inside the loop).

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is a state machine, so the only important rule is, that you set state when you need it and whenever it changes. You need a certain line width? Set it and be done width. You need a number of different line widths in a single code segment: Sort by line width and set once for every line width.

Some states are expensive to switch, so it's a good idea to keep track of those; in particular the states in question are anything related to texture binding (either to a texture unit or as FBO attachment) and shaders. Everything else is actually quite cheap to change.

In general it's a good idea to set OpenGL state explicitly and don't assume certain states being preset from earlier. This also covers the transformation matrices and setup: Do a full viewport and projection setup at every beginning of the display function; advanced applications will have to change those multiple times drawing a single frame anyway (so no glViewport, glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION), ... in a reshape handler).

Comment: "In general it's a good idea to set OpenGL state explicitly and don't assume certain states being preset from earlier." I disagree with this from a performance point of view. Minimizing state changes is good for performance; a well-structured rendering engine will sort by major state changes and *only* make the minimum number of changes to render the next thing. This means assuming what has come before.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: This is a tradeoff between the amount of CPU time you want to spend on OpenGL state bookkeeping, or actually get stuff done. Some changes are expensive, namely switching textures (it invalidates caches) and shaders or switching FBOs. And the rest is usually very cheap. Optimizing OpenGL state changes is just another kind of micro optimization. And one usually only begins micro optimizing if each and every microsecond matters. Much larger performance gains are achieved by broad algorithmic optimization.

Comment: @datenwolf Which is why I prefaced my answer with "you should profile and verify that this actually matters to performance." So I'm _assuming_ that this has already been identified as a bottleneck.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: It also stongly depends on the kind of application one is developing. In a game your primary objective is high rendering performance. However OpenGL is used in other areas than games, too. For example in CAD and 3D modellers. Take Blender for example where not only the 3D Views but everything is rendered using OpenGL. And not just code in the Blener core use OpenGL, but also many Add On (written in Python) have full access to OpenGL; this makes it literally impossible to keep track of the OpenGL state and sort by state changes. This makes explicit state setting a neccesity.

Comment: @datenwolf: Also true. But if a person is asking about whether they should be repeatedly setting state, the only reason for such a question would be that they're concerned about the performance of their application. Therefore, it makes sense to talk about things in terms of what is _best_ for performance. Now personally I wouldn't bother with such a thing without serious and comprehensive profiling data in hand to make sure it was worthwhile (and even then I'd look for lower-hanging fruit first). But that wasn't his question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Even if one identified state changes as a bottleneck, the impact of the micro changes uses to depend largely on the driver in use. A few years ago I wrote a little benchmark for exactly this and found huge variations of the effects between driver versions, both positive and negative. What resulted in better performance with the current driver, may perform worse on another. NVidia is known to include application specific optimizations into their drivers, and I'm betting they also provision for the state change pattern of the applications in question.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are drawing tens to hundreds of thousands of lines, it really won't matter. And even then, you should profile and verify that this actually matters to performance. But let's assume you did that.

Minimizing the number of state changes *could* improve your performance. This means that you should sort your lines by line size and your points by point size. That way, lines that are all the same size can be drawn at the same time. This of course assumes that you could draw the lines in any order. If you need the lines to be drawn in a certain order, then you will have to live with the state changes.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid glGet** functions to determine current line width / point size. It is a big performance eater.

Instead store current property localy and update when necessary (preferred), or use glPushAttrib(GL_LINE_BIT) / glPopAttrib.